# listfragment on item click

Tags: android, listadapter, android-listfragment

my app is a simple notepad kind of app, in this fragment i want to retrieve notes from the database and put them into the list-fragment. It works good until i want to choose one of the list items i have to click on the text of the list and not on the list item like other list-fragments.

here is the code

```
 public void fillData() {

        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(getActivity());
        mDbHelper.open();

        Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();


        String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

       int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1};        

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using row
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ListAdapter adapter = new  SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),    R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

this the listener method

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent N = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteEdit.class);
    N.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(N, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}
```

notes_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Comment: How do you set your item click listener ?

Comment: @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent N = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteEdit.class);
    N.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(N, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

Comment: Can you share your `notes_row.xml` ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:singleLine="true"/>